# Capture written text without focusing input element

Tags: javascript, html, input, dom-events

I am trying to achieve simple scenario:

- I want to capture keyboard events on the document
- I want to update text from those events like the input element or textarea does

To put that in an example, imagine that you have some element with focus and you want to track the text that's written into it (for example some simple filtering). I don't want to create some visible input element and giving it focus.

I tried naive solution like delegating event to another element (input in this case), because I still need to translate keyCode to valid character according to system locale etc.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script>
        function initialize() {
            console.log('initializing');
            var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
            var input = document.getElementById('text');

            function delegateEvent(e) {
                if (e.__delegate) {
                    return;
                }

                var ev = new e.constructor(e.type, e);
                ev.keyCode = e.keyCode;
                ev.__delegate = true;
                input.dispatchEvent(ev);
            }

            body.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
                delegateEvent(e);
            }, false);
            body.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
                delegateEvent(e);
            }, false);

            input.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
                console.log('input keydown', e);
            });

            input.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
                console.log('input keyup', e);
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()" tabindex="0">
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="text" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

However this does not work for me. For some reason unknown to me, the KeyboardEvent is delegated to input element, but it does not change text at all.

What's wrong with that example?

Is there any better way how to achieve results in my given case? Simply I need to update text, that's being processed by some non-input element.

Comment: "I don't want to create some visible input element and giving it focus." what dos it mean ? I cant understand that 
do you want to type it on the document itself ?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to capture key events from the document and pass them to the input for processing. Can you explain why you want to do that (rather than just updating the value of the input element based on the events?)

Comment: Sounds like a key-logger to me :)

Answer (score 2):

This might help:

```
var input = document.getElementById('text');

function appendCharacter (c) {
    switch (c) {
        case 8: // Backspace
            input.value = input.value.slice(0, -1);
            break;
        default:
            input.value = input.value + String.fromCharCode(c);
    }
}

// Keypress gets the keyCode of the current character not key.
// e.g. pressing the 'A' key will result in 'a' unless 'Shift' is also held.
window.addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
    console.log(e.charCode)
    console.log(e.keyCode)
    appendCharacter(e.keyCode);
});

// Use Keydown to get special keys like Backspace, Enter, Esc.
window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 8: // Backspace
            e.preventDefault(); // Stops the backspace key from acting like the back button.
            appendCharacter(e.keyCode);
            break;
    }
});
```

Try it out: https://jsfiddle.net/vuoriliikaluoma/9u29wyzd/

Comment: This is just a partial solution, which I have in my past implementation (roughly similar). Imagine control keys like BACKSPACE, DELETE and others. I am sure that not all features from text-editing inputs are necessary in this case, but at least basic text control functions should be usable too. I can imagine writing some controlling code like `if (isBackspace(e)) deleteChar()` etc. but the main reason that I asked this question was to determine all possibilities.

Comment: I've updated the code for dealing with backspace and similar. Check it out.